# Como converter data com hora para data no select query?

Tags: mysql

Segue a foto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
select dt_abertura, count(1) as qtd
from tabela
group by dt_abertura;
```

Como converter data com hora **(2017-09-23 16:24:55)** para apenas data **(23-09-2017)** ?

Gostaria de conseguir agrupar esse valores por ordem de data
exemplo:

01-01-2017 em seguida em baixo
02 -01- 2017 e por ae vai

Comment: Você quer mostrar apenas a data na hora do select ?

Comment: Sim, e conseguir agrupar a quantidade de registros dela

Comment: Tenta essa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query

Comment: Veja a resposta do Tony e não esquece de dar ✔️.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jvebxy
Não funcionou como eu esperava

Comment: Francisco comenta isso no comentário da resposta do Tony abaixo.

Answer (score 3):

Consegui arrumar do jeito que eu queria:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt_abertura,"%d/%m/%Y") AS Data, count(1) as qtd
FROM tabela
group by DATE_FORMAT(dt_abertura,"%d/%m/%Y")
order by date(dt_abertura);
```

Veja o resultado:

[image: resposta]

Obrigado a todos que tentaram me ajudar.

Comment: Posta seu código, esse link pode quebrar um dia e ninguém terá acesso ao código!

Comment: Novo aqui malz :)

Comment: Vale a pena dá uma olhadinha https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(dt_abertura, '%Y/%m/%d'), count(1) as qtd
from tabela
group by DATE_FORMAT(dt_abertura, '%Y/%m/%d');
```

*Docs*:  ***[DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)***.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jvelta n deu certo aqui não, o resultado que eu esperava era o seguinte : http://prntscr.com/jvemcz , os numeros na frente seria a quantidade .

Comment: Tente usando o `DATE_FORMAT`

Answer (score 0):

Testado com MySQL 5.7.12:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(CAST(CAST('2018-06-15 17:22:00' AS DATETIME) AS UNSIGNED) / 1000000) AS DATE);
```

No seu caso, seria

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(CAST(dt_abertura AS UNSIGNED) / 1000000) AS DATE) AS data, COUNT(*) AS qtd
FROM tabela
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```